# Script which check who login by "su -"

Tags: linux, shell-script, users, non-root-user

I need find a way to list all current users which are using root account by `su -`
For example:

```
bob@test:~$ su -
root@test:~#
```

```
alice@test:~$ su -
root@test:~#
```

And now list normal users which using root account (at this moment).

Have You got any idea?

Comment: do you want to list the users which **can** execute `su -`? or the ones which actually using `su -`?

Comment: I want use the ones which actually using su -

Comment: why do you want to get the list of the owns who uses `su -`? are you aware that they can remove any traces for that (if they like to do it)?

Comment: depending on your country and legal issue this could be illegal. You should first know if you have the right to identify user by name doing certain things. If you need your best possibility is to read shell history file of each user, but it's not reliable. To start from now , I would advise you to monitor access to su binary using inotify

Comment: Assuming that you are the owner of the computer - why do you give `su -` rights to people that you don't trust, and you wish to follow their action?

Comment: We have got 5 admins and rarely developer who have root access over short time. So I want to know when is he using root account.

Comment: again - if you don't trust someone with root access, why don't you revoke the access?

Comment: It's not about trust. I just want to know.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Are you just curious? Do you understand that once someone is `root` she can hide her traces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours I did it :)

Output for future users:

```
who | sort -k2 > /tmp/whoresult ; pgrep -x su | xargs -i ps hu -p{} | awk '{printf $7 " ";for (i=11; i<=NF; i++) printf $i " "; printf "\n"}' | sort -k1 | join -1 2 -2 1 /tmp/whoresult - | awk '{print $2  "("$8")"}' | sed -e "s|()|(root)|g" | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep "Successful su for root" /var/log/auth.log|sed -e 's/.*by //'|sort -u`

Comment: Note that if someone has root access (e.g. after issuing `su -`) and want to hide it, she can easily remove that line from the `/var/log/auth.log` file (especially as it is a text file)